# Consultar datos de relacion ManyToMany

Tags: jsp, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc

Hay una relacion de N:M entre Boleta y Libro y deseo hacer una consulta, pero no sé como hacerlo. He estado investigando pero solo veo muchas formas usando Spring Boot con Repository no sé que más, pero sucede que aún no conozco ese, estoy aprendiendo. Pero encontré una forma digamos e intenté esto, pero aun así no me funciona:

**boleta**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "boletas")
public class Boleta implements Serializable {


        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name = "detalle_libros",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "boleta_id", nullable = false,
                foreignKey = @ForeignKey(foreignKeyDefinition
                        = "foreign key(boleta_id) references boletas(idBoleta)")),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "libro_id", nullable = false,
                foreignKey = @ForeignKey(foreignKeyDefinition
                        = "foreign key(libro_id) references libros(libroId)")))

        private Set<Libro> listaLibros = new HashSet<>();


    // getters y setters
}
```

**libro**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "libros")
public class Libro implements Serializable {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "listaLibros", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Boleta> listaBoletas = new HashSet<>();
     
    // getters y setters
}
```

**libroController**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/libro_boleta", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String libro_boleta_GET(Map map) {
    map.put("lLibro", libroService.FindlibroBoletas());

    return "libroBoleta";
}
```

**libroServiceImpl**

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Collection<Libro> FindlibroBoletas() {
    Collection<Libro> books = findAll();

    for (Libro book : books) {
        Set<Boleta> bookBoleta = book.getListaBoletas();
    }

    Collection<Boleta> boletas = boletaDao.findAll();

    for (Boleta boleta : boletas) {
        Set<Libro> boletaBooks = boleta.getListaLibros();
    }

    return books;
}
```

**libroBoleta.jsp**

```
<table>
        <c:forEach var="libro" items="${lLibro}">
            <tr>
                <td>${libro.libroId}</td>
                <td>${libro.titulo}</td>
                <td>${libro.edicion}</td>
                <td>${libro.listaBoletas}</td>
                <c:forEach var="boleta" items="${libro.listaBoletas}">
                    <td>${boleta.fechaInicio}</td>
                    <td>${boleta.fechaInicio}</td>
                    <td>${boleta.mora}</td>
                </c:forEach>
                <td>
                    <a href="<c:url value='/libro_editar/${libro.libroId}'/>">Editar</a> |
                    <a href="<c:url value='/libro_borrar/${libro.libroId}'/>">Borrar</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

He intentado de esta forma y no me funciona. Lo que quiero hacer es listar las boletas con sus respectivos libros, nada mas. Ayuda por favor

Comment: En `LibroServiceImpl` ¿qué quieres hacer con los `for`? Estás definiendo variables que no usas para nada. Solo la primera y la última línea del método parecen tener sentido.

Comment: Sucede que vi un ejemplo pero quité lo que me indicaste y tampoco funciona, en el caso de la segunda lista, solo me muestra un " [] ".